# Determine if a triangle is on the screen

Tags: rendering, algorithm, intersection, culling, software-rendering

I am working on a small software renderer, and I want to discard invisible triangles from the drawing process. Let's say I have a screen with resolution of 200x100 pixels. The triangle is defined with three 2-dimensional coordinates `{x, y}` in the screen space.

What is the **fastest possible way to get a yes/no answer for the question "Should my triangle be drawn?"**, I don't need to retrieve intersection coordinates, just a boolean answer.

**Note**: on the image below all four red triangles need to be drawn even though some of their vertices aren't on the screen.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

There are three kinds of positional relationship between two plane figures: disjoint, one inside the other, partial intersection. You need to check for partial intersection and one inside the other.

1. **One inside the other**. It means one's vertices are all in the other.

   [check_point_in_triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049582/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-in-a-2d-triangle)

   [check_point_in_rectangle](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-given-point-lies-inside-rectangle-not/)

[image]

In fact, the check can be ended if at least one point is inside the target graph, since it covers the case of partial intersection.

[image]

2. **Partial intersection**. It means that two graphs have at least two edges that intersect.

   [check_two_segments_intersect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838329/how-can-i-check-if-two-segments-intersect)

[image]